# How to find a value in one column into multiple another columns in SQL

Tags: sql

My data is something like :

```
C1,  C2,  C3,   C4,   C5  
10,  1,   101,  60,   80   
10,  1,   201,  70,   101    
10,  2,   101,  80,   201    
10,  2,   30,   700,  90  
10,  5,   12,   12,   12
```

I want to find:

All the values which are in c2 whether the exists in C3,C4 or C5.
Similarly all the values in C3 exists in C4 and C5 and so on.

Final output will be :

```
C1,  C2,  C3,   C4,   C5  
10,  1,   101,  60,   80   
10,  1,   201,  70,   101    
10,  2,   101,  80,   201
```

as for other two records no value in C3,C4 and C5 exits in any other column.

Regards,
A

Comment: I don't understand what you are after. You might need to show us the result that you want, and expand your explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the logic to be "for the current row, under what conditions should it be included?"

My reading of your question is that a row is included if:

> It's C5 value appears in any other row's C2 or C3 or C4
> OR
> It's C4 value appears in any other row's C2 or C3
> OR
> It's C3 value appears in any other row's C2

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM yourTable AS lookup
     WHERE yourTable.c5 IN (lookup.c2, lookup.c3, lookup.c4)
        OR yourTable.c4 IN (lookup.c2, lookup.c3)
        OR yourTable.c3 IN (lookup.c2)
  )
```

Although you didn't state it, you might also need `WHERE (blah) AND yourTable.c1 = lookup.c1`

Comment: It's C2 value appears in any other row's C3 or C4 or C5
OR
It's C3 value appears in any other row's C4 or C5
OR
It's C4 value appears in any other row's C5

Comment: Thanks MatBailie for introducing me to lookup in sql.

Comment: @user13472171 `It's C2 value appears in any other row's C3 or C4 or C5` - No, that's not what your question said, your question said `if a row's C2 value appears in another row's C3, C4 or C5, include that other row`, this answer specifically states to term in such that `this row is included if` rather than `the other row is included if`

Comment: @user13472171 `lookup` is just an alias for the table.  You could still run that code if you replaced all occurences of `lookup` with `smeg`